# Update Using Case Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I perform an update using a case clause based on the following query using SQL in SQL Management Studio:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN t1.building is null THEN 0
ELSE t1.building END AS Building,
t1.id, 
CASE WHEN t1.building is null THEN 0
ELSE t2.count END AS Count
FROM table t1
JOIN (SELECT building, COUNT(*) as count 
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY building) AS t2 ON t2.building = t1.building OR (t2.building is 
  null AND t1.building is null)
```

The following does not work:

```
Update table
Set count=(Select count from table where count in( 
SELECT 
CASE WHEN t1.building is null THEN 0
ELSE t1.building END AS Building,
t1.id, 
CASE WHEN t1.building is null THEN 0
ELSE t2.count END AS Count
FROM table t1
JOIN (SELECT building, COUNT(*) as count 
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY building) AS t2 ON t2.building = t1.building OR (t2.building is 
  null AND t1.building is null))
```

My objective is to update the count column with values based off the original query per id number.

From:

```
ID  Building  Count
1    10        
2    10        
3    11        
4    11        
5    11        
6    Null
```

Desired Results:

```
ID  Building  Count
1    10        2
2    10        2
3    11        3
4    11        3
5    11        3
6    Null      0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: This feels like a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `JOIN UPDATE` with `CASE WHEN`

```
UPDATE t1
SET Count = CASE WHEN t1.Building IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t2.cnt END
FROM T t1
LEFT JOIN (
  select Building,COUNT(Building) cnt
  from T
  GROUP BY Building
) t2 on t1.Building = t2.Building
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b3be/1)

Comment: @sqlfiddle, your script works but I get an error:Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @Jeff because you need to select with  `NULL` COUNT in subquery.  you can set `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/13/sql-server-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation/

Comment: When I SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, I also get an error: Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 66
UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Comment: If you can't set it you can also use `ISNULL` to slove it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/85b83/1

Comment: Or perhaps just add `where Building is not null` in t2?

Comment: @LukStorms  Yes it's another option because the query `outer join` base on `t1`